# Looking for a JQuery table API that can

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

im looking for a JQuery table plugin/library capable of doing the following;

1. Accept raw tables
2. Sort on columns
3. Hide and show rows based on checkbox selections
4. Ignore/maintain "hidden" rows (rows that contain additional information for the previous row, visibility toggle-able from a link inside the primary row)
5. Assign/re-assign "odd"/"even" classes based on sorting and selection
6. Maintain Javascript events triggered from inside the table
7. Pagination support

So far i have found Dynatable which seems to support 4 out of 7 of my requirements.

Comment: use jqgrid http://www.trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/jqgrid.html

Comment: jquery datatable 1.10 + have you looked into it .

Comment: im looking into it yes. playing with motties fork at the moment though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I maintain a [fork of tablesorter](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/) which covers almost all of your requirements:

1. By "raw" tables I guess you mean a table already in the DOM.
2. It is called tablesorter... and it allows sorting multiple columns at once
3. There is a [column selector widget](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/example-widget-column-selector.html) for this purpose.
4. Use the [child row class name](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/#csschildrow) on row(s) you want to sort with their parent; you'll need to include the code to hide/show that row
5. This is the function of the [zebra widget](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/example-widget-zebra.html).
6. I don't think there are *any* plugins that can do this since the rows are dynamically added/removed when sorting; It would be best to use [delegated events](http://api.jquery.com/on/#direct-and-delegated-events) when binding to elements within the tbody.
7. You can use the [pager widget](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/example-widget-pager.html) to add pagination.

The [DataTables](http://www.datatables.net/) plugin also covers all of these requirements. Although, I find it a bit more complicated to learn to use.

Comment: Thank you, where can i find your source and documentation?

Comment: Oh sorry, I forgot to add the url to my answer... [docs](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/) & [source](https://github.com/Mottie/tablesorter)

Comment: regarding number 3, yours hides the column, i wish to hide rows that contain a value

Comment: Do you mean like using a table filter? With the available [filter widget](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/example-widget-filter.html) you can search for data that is a `!` (not match) or `!=` (not exactly equal) to a query. If that isn't want you want, then you can write a custom widget to search for and hide rows that contain specific values.